# How can I erase my save & start fresh in Crypt of the Necrodancer on Steam for PC?

Tags: steam, pc, crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I've just started up *Crypt of the Necrodancer: Amplified* on Steam for PC for the first time in ages. I'm playing version 3, the update that dropped today, and it seems like I've got an old save loaded up. I'm starting with six hearts, every room in the lobby is unlocked, the shops are all mostly empty, I have zones 1–5 unlocked, etc. I *assume* this isn't just the default starting state of a fresh save in this version of the game—I remember having to fight through the dungeon to have to unlock each shopkeeper, and I imagine the shops shouldn't be empty!

I'd like to reset my progress to a clean slate and start like new. I can't for the life of me figure out how to erase my progress though. Every time I *attempt* to clear my save based on things I've found on Google, it doesn't change anything.

Things I've tried include the following:

1. Search the in-game menu for an option to clear save data, like we had in 2.x.
2. Open Misc Options to enable advanced settings, and search again.
3. Set “Save on Exit: Off” and restart, in the hopes that means no save.
4. Go to Crypt of the Necrodancer → Properties → General, and disable cloud saves for this game.
5. Delete the `save_data.xml` file at `steamapps\common\Crypt of the NecroDancer\data`, although in my case it had a string of numbers in the filename as well.
6. Go to `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/`, open the subfolder with numbers (my user ID), find the subfolder *in there* named `247080` (the Crypt of the Necromancer game ID), and delete it. There's no folder for `554000` (the Amplified DLC game ID).
7. Uninstall and reinstall the game while cloud saves are disabled.

Still, whatever I do, when I start the game it's just the same as before:

[image: the permanent upgrade shop and neighbouring shops, all empty but for one item]

**What do I need to do to start from a fresh save in this version of the game?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a file at `%AppData%/NecroDancer` named `SynchronyConfig.lua`. It contains a record of my local configuration, but it also stores all my unlocks and progression:

[image: a sample of my progress from the file]

Deleting this file appears to reset my progress and give me a fresh start at the game.